# Expectation in kernel density estimate

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning, expectation

> Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables with common density $f$.
>   Let $K(\cdot)$ be a probability density function defined on the real line.
>   Then for a nonstochastic $h$:
>
> $$E[\hat{f}]=\frac{1}{nh}\sum_{i=1}^n E\left[K\left(\frac{x-X_i}{h}\right)\right]$$
>   $$=\frac{1}{h}E\left[K\left(\frac{x-X_i}{h}\right)\right]=\frac{1}{h}\int
>  K\left(\frac{x-u}{h}\right)f(u)du$$ $$=\int K(y)f(x+hy)dy$$

I'm having trouble to understand how they get the two last equalities. Since $K$ is a probability density function

$$\frac{1}{h}E[K\left(\frac{x-X_i}{h}\right)]=\frac{1}{h}\int K\left(\frac{x-X_i}{h}\right)d\left(\frac{x-X_i}{h}\right)$$

but I had a density that is function of another density.

Anyone can help me understood that?

Comment: I think the last equality (within the yellow box) is written incorrectly; I believe the + should be a -.

Comment: It's not stated in the problem, but if $K(\cdot)$ is symmetric then you can write
$$\frac{1}{h}\int K\left(\frac{x-u}{h}\right)f(u)du = \frac{1}{h}\int K\left(\frac{u-x}{h}\right)f(u)du.$$ and use $y=\frac{u-x}{h}$ as the substitution. I think $K(\cdot)$ being symmetric is a necessary assumption because otherwise $dy = \frac{-1}{h}du$, leaving a $-1$ that is unaccounted for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you know that for a (bounded, measurable) function $g$, you have
$$
\mathbb{E}[g(X_i)] = \int g(u) f(u)\, du
$$
So, set $g(u) = K\left(\frac{x - u}{h}\right)$ and the first confusion is settled.

For the second, use the change of variables $y = \frac{x - u}{ h}$.

Answer (score 1):

1. $K(\cdot)$ is not a pdf for $X_i$.
2. $y = \dfrac{x-u}{h}$ and therefore $u = x - yh$, it seems to be a mistake in thr last expression.